# SQL Pivot double sum

Tags: sql-server-2012, sum, pivot

I have the following query result:

```
dday         showtime             qty    total
2019-06-03   Sat 22/6 - 2:30 PM   1      50.00
2019-06-03   Sat 22/6 - 7:00 PM   1      50.00
2019-06-04   NULL                 NULL   NULL
```

I'd like to pivot this and show a new result, putting the showtime as columns, summing the "qty" and the total per "dday", like this:

```
DAY     [Fri 21/6 - 7:00 PM]   [Sat 22/6 - 2:30 PM]   [Sat 22/6 - 7:00 PM]   TICKETS   AMOUNT
Jun 3   0                      1                      1                      2         100.00
Jun 4   0                      0                      0                      0         NULL
```

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(CHAR(4), dday, 0) + CAST(DAY(dday) AS VARCHAR) 'DAY'
    , SUM(ISNULL([Thu 20/6  - 7:00 PM],0)) [Thu 20/6  - 7:00 PM],SUM(ISNULL([Fri 21/6  - 7:00 PM],0)) [Fri 21/6  - 7:00 PM],SUM(ISNULL([Sat 22/6  - 2:30 PM],0)) [Sat 22/6  - 2:30 PM],SUM(ISNULL([Sat 22/6  - 7:00 PM],0)) [Sat 22/6  - 7:00 PM]
    , SUM(ISNULL([Thu 20/6  - 7:00 PM],0)+ISNULL([Fri 21/6  - 7:00 PM],0)+ISNULL([Sat 22/6  - 2:30 PM],0)+ISNULL([Sat 22/6  - 7:00 PM],0)) 'TICKETS'
    , SUM(total) 'AMOUNT'
FROM   z
PIVOT
(
    MAX(qty)
    FOR showtime IN ([Thu 20/6  - 7:00 PM],[Fri 21/6  - 7:00 PM],[Sat 22/6  - 2:30 PM],[Sat 22/6  - 7:00 PM])
) AS P 
GROUP BY dday
ORDER BY dday
```

But I'm getting this result:

```
DAY     [Fri 21/6 - 7:00 PM]   [Sat 22/6 - 2:30 PM]   [Sat 22/6 - 7:00 PM]   TICKETS   AMOUNT
Jun 3   0                      1                      1                      2         50.00
Jun 4   0                      0                      0                      0         NULL
```

The qty "tickets" sum is correct, but why the amount sum show me 50.00 instead 100.00??

***Alternative***

I've used another alternative, applying OUTER APPLY:

```
SELECT
     CONVERT(CHAR(4), dday, 0) + CAST(DAY(dday) AS VARCHAR) 'DAY'
    , SUM(ISNULL([Thu 20/6  - 7:00 PM],0)) [Thu 20/6  - 7:00 PM],SUM(ISNULL([Fri 21/6  - 7:00 PM],0)) [Fri 21/6  - 7:00 PM],SUM(ISNULL([Sat 22/6  - 2:30 PM],0)) [Sat 22/6  - 2:30 PM],SUM(ISNULL([Sat 22/6  - 7:00 PM],0)) [Sat 22/6  - 7:00 PM]
    , SUM(ISNULL([Thu 20/6  - 7:00 PM],0)+ISNULL([Fri 21/6  - 7:00 PM],0)+ISNULL([Sat 22/6  - 2:30 PM],0)+ISNULL([Sat 22/6  - 7:00 PM],0)) 'TICKETS'
    , SUPERTOTAL 'AMOUNT'
FROM   z AS j
OUTER APPLY
 ( 
    SELECT SUM(total) 'SUPERTOTAL'
    FROM z AS x
    WHERE x.dday = j.dday
 ) x
PIVOT
(
    MAX(qty)
    FOR showtime IN ([Thu 20/6  - 7:00 PM],[Fri 21/6  - 7:00 PM],[Sat 22/6  - 2:30 PM],[Sat 22/6  - 7:00 PM])
) AS P 
GROUP BY dday, SUPERTOTAL
ORDER BY dday
```

In that case, it works, but I really needed apply this "subquery" for each additional sum? Is it possible to get my desired result in one pivot?

Comment: You have enough reputation to know that images of data is poorly received. Please do take the time to provide data as formatted `text`, or as DDL and DML statements; rather than expecting the volunteers to transcribe your images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to easily get the overall `Total` and also the `Tickets` total by adding a couple of uses of windowing functions to the query. If you use a `sum(<col>) over(partition by <col>)` to your query you can simplify things bit.

For an example, if your table is:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
    ([dday] datetime, [showtime] varchar(18), [qty] int, [total] decimal(10,2))
;

INSERT INTO yourtable
    ([dday], [showtime], [qty], [total])
VALUES
    ('2019-06-03 00:00:00', 'Sat 22/6 - 2:30 PM', 8017, 50.00),
    ('2019-06-03 00:00:00', 'Sat 22/6 - 7:00 PM', 5019, 50.00),
    ('2019-06-04 00:00:00', NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

You could change the query to be:

```
select 
    CONVERT(CHAR(4), dday, 0) + CAST(DAY(dday) AS VARCHAR) 'DAY'
    ,ISNULL([Thu 20/6  - 7:00 PM],0) [Thu 20/6  - 7:00 PM]
    ,ISNULL([Fri 21/6  - 7:00 PM],0) [Fri 21/6  - 7:00 PM]
    ,ISNULL([Sat 22/6  - 2:30 PM],0) [Sat 22/6  - 2:30 PM]
    ,ISNULL([Sat 22/6  - 7:00 PM],0) [Sat 22/6  - 7:00 PM]
    , Isnull(Tickets, 0) Tickets
    , IsNull(Total, 0) Total
from
(
    SELECT 
        dday,
        showtime, 
        qty,
        Tickets= sum(qty) over(partition by dday),
        Total = sum(Total) over(partition by dday)
    FROM   yourtable
) d
PIVOT
(
    MAX(qty)
    FOR showtime IN ([Thu 20/6  - 7:00 PM],[Fri 21/6  - 7:00 PM],[Sat 22/6  - 2:30 PM],[Sat 22/6  - 7:00 PM])
) AS P
```

The difference is that inside of the subquery I used:

```
Tickets= sum(qty) over(partition by dday),
Total = sum(Total) over(partition by dday)
```

This is creating a sum of the tickets and the Total for each `dday`, if you use this before you `PIVOT` the data you'll have the same value before you are applying the `GROUP BY` aspect of the `PIVOT` function.